# Global sections of a line bundle on a hypersurface in complex projective space.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, line-bundles

Let  $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n $ be a complex hypersurface of degree $d$. I'm trying to calculate the global sections of $\mathcal{O}(r)_{|X}$ for $r \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is what (I think) I have so far:

By the long exact sequence in cohomology and Kodaira Vanishing theorem we have a short exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(r-d)) \to H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(r)) \to H^0(X,\mathcal{O}(r)_{|X}) \to 0$$

I can identify $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(r)) $ with homogeneous polynomials  of degree $r$.

As I understand it, the second map in the above sequence is induced by tensoring the map $ j^\sharp: \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n} \to j_* \mathcal{O}_X $, where $j:X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$, with $\mathcal{O}(r)$, and then applying the projection formula.

1) does what I've written make sense?

2) If so, how does $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{O}(r-d))$ get identified with the kernel here? Do I need to look at the first map given by the inclusion of the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_X \cong \mathcal{O}(-d)$?

Apologies if I'm being real stupid here.

Comment: Let $X$ be defined by $f$. Then the first map is defined by multiplication by $f$. I am not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble seeing it is this map. I will think and then fill out an answer later. This would be pretty much what I want.

Comment: OK i see that multiplication by $f$ induces the inclusion of the ideal sheaf now. This is pretty much all I need. Thanks!

Comment: If one want users other than the one who asked the question to get notified, one must use @[name of the user] while commenting. I thought you are new here and didn't know this.

Comment: @random123 OK! cool